# Fedora 22 instalation

Tags: fedora, boot

I have created the live image on my USB. I tried to install the sysem but I could not. I have one hard drive (1 TB). So far I have Windows 7 installed on it. I separated one partition for Fedora instalation. All my partitions are converted to basic (not logic) with NTFS file system (I could not set other). When I had boot USB drive and started instlation with GUI, I was asked to chose drive. Unfortunately only one hard drive was recognized - my 1TB drive with xxx free space. I also tried to delete partition in Windows system and left it as unassigned space. It did not work either. My question is: how to prepare my hard drive to have both systems (Windows and Linux) installed on different partitions. I want to chose which one to boot on computer startup.

Comment: when i installed fedora in my computer which had ubuntu, what i did was - i created free space, then started the live usb, then selected the hard disk (yes the same hard disk in which ubuntu was),and selected `automatic` paritioning, then clicked  next, next ... to begin installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only one drive it makes sense that anaconda (that's the installer) only detects one.

What you will need to do is select that drive and then select the extra partition you created for the installation. If you remove that and then select either a manual partition setup or the default one. If you are new I suggest to stick with the default.

The installer will take care of seeing up grub to ensure you can choose which os to boot.

Just make sure to select the right partition so you don't accidentally delete your Windows installation.